# React Parent Input, only render onBlur, mouse outside textbox

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

Everytime, I update/write a letter in Child Textbox component,  all of Parent component renders. How do I make it so, component only rerenders when onBlur, or user leaves the textbox? Using MUI 5 .

**Parent Component:**

```
const ProductDashboard = () => {
     const [productName, setProductName] = useState<null | string>('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
  }, [productName]);

  return (
      <ProductFilter
```

**Child:**

```
const ProductFilter = ({
  productName,
  setProductName,

  return (
    <Box>
      <TextField
        value={productNameValue}
        onChange={event => {
          onFeeNameChange(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `defaultValue` prop and `onBlur` handler:

```
const ProductFilter = ({ defaultValue, onComplete }) => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <TextField
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        onBlur={(e) => onComplete(e.target.value)}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
<ProductFilter defaultValue={productName} onComplete={setProductName} />
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-forked-zmqf6h?file=/index.js)

Comment: onBlur={(e) => onComplete(value)}
  do you mean, onComplete(e.target.value). ? Thanks for the code btw !

Comment: My pleasure. It's the same in this case.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You only need internal state in more complex cases.